# How to copy the server database to my local Machine to generate scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My boss said 
"To do so, SCRIPT the real database using SQL Manager / Tasks
RUN that script locally in a Query Window on your own machine to create a local copy of the database.

Note:  Your new database will have all Tables and Procedures but will have NO data in it.  You will need to add your own "dummy data" to make things work for you as you test.

Create a second connection string in your `web.config` that connects to your local database
use that connection string for your development work

However i don't actually understand how to do that.

Comment: @Div backup file of DB will have data in it and that's not required. We need to create scripts for this

Comment: quoting from OP  `NOTE: Your new database will have all Tables and Procedures but will have NO data in it.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:

```
1. Connect to your remote server from SQL Server Management Studio.
2. In object explorer, right click on your database and select Tasks>Generate Scripts.
3. Click on Next and then again click on Next.
4. Select the file system path where you want to save the database script for the database and click on Next
5. Click on Next. A .sql file will generated.
6. Connect to your local server from SQL Server Management Studio.
7. Open the newly created database script in SQL Server Management Studio and execute it. A copy of your database on remote server will
be created on your local server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answer above, change the connection string in your web.config by changing the name of the data source to your Server Name (the name you use to get into SQL Server) and change the initial catalog to the name of your local database. Provide additional username and password fields if you're using SQL Server authentication. If you're using Windows Authentication specify it.

Example string for SQL Server Authentication:

```
<add name="YourEntities" connectionString="*your metadata link*;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=**your server name**;Initial Catalog=**your database name**;User ID=**your username**;Password=**your password**; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Just change the values of the attributes **data source, initial catalog, username and password**.

For windows authentication:
Add the following attribute:

```
Integrated Security=True;
```

and remove attributes username and password.