# How to copy a database with all its contents with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, active-directory

So I have a task to create a method that would read a set of users from a source, compare the set with the database and if users are not found in source flag them as deleted in DB, and if users are in source, but not found in the DB it should add them. The code is in place, however in case it doesn't work the code will flag all users in the database as deleted. This is why I would like make a local copy of my present database with all its contents, to test my code without breaking the DB for all people working on it at the moment.

I found this post: [How to copy the server database to my local Machine to generate scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40394787/how-to-copy-the-server-database-to-my-local-machine-to-generate-scripts)

However, I am not sure if it will copy only the structure of the database, or the structure with all the data?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You can use the database (localdb) that comes with vs2019.